# Convert json object to strings to store them in firestore database

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have used `flutter_form_bloc` to add and remove text fields according to the requirement.
The json object is generated for the text fields, which when printed in console using `print()` and the below is the output in the console with 3 textfields generated.

I want to convert the json object to so that it generates the `String values` for every textfield generated so that those strings can be added to the firestore database.

How can I achieve that?

```
flutter: {
    "members": [
        {
            "firstName": "hi jhji"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "dfasdfa"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "DFASDFASD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code of Json Object

```
FormBlocListener<ListFieldFormBloc, String, String>(
                onSubmitting: (context, state) {
                  //LoadingDialog.show(context);
                },
                onSuccess: (context, state) {
                //  LoadingDialog.hide(context);


                  //json object printing
                  print(state.successResponse);

                },
                onFailure: (context, state) {
                 // LoadingDialog.hide(context);

                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text(state.failureResponse)));
                },
```

Comment: So you want to get the string value of each member and store it firestore?

Comment: @ByteMe Yes, I want string values in array and store that array in the firestore document

Comment: You can convert a JSON object in the form of a string using the dart:convert library [1]. Look at this sample code [2]. I couldn't try with the flutter_form_bloc syntax, but the syntax should be similar. Read this [3].

  [1]: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html
  [2]: https://pastebin.com/pVDus1JQ
  [3]: https://giancarlocode.github.io/form_bloc